# SoapClient30 give error in window 7 64 bit

Tags: vba, deprecated, soap-client

I am using VBA 7. When I attempt to create a new object for `Set sc_SearchEngineXML = New SoapClient30`, it gives me an error stating that the ActiveX component cannot create the object.

Is there any alternate solutions that I can use in place of the deprecated SOAP Toolkits?

As per [MSDN](http://support.microsoft.com/gp/lifedevtool):

> All SOAP Toolkits have been replaced by the Microsoft .NET Framework.
>   The .NET Framework provides basic Web service capabilities with COM
>   components and applications. SOAP Toolkit versions prior to 3.0 are no
>   longer supported. Support for SOAP Toolkit 3.0 has been extended
>   beyond the original retirement date of July 1, 2004 to more closely
>   align with the support offered for Visual Studio 6.0. Standard support
>   for SOAP Toolkit 3.0 will now expire March 31, 2005 and extended
>   support will expire April 8, 2008. For the latest information about
>   supported technologies for developing Web services, visit the Web
>   Services Developer Center on the MSDN Web site. To learn about the
>   benefits of building Web services solutions on the .NET Framework and
>   to take advantage of the latest advanced Web services capabilities,
>   read the MSDN articles on migration.

Please help me out.

Comment: In 64-bit system where the 64-bit Excel is installed try to look for shared files folder, e.g. for `Office 16` it could look like this: `C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\OFFICE16` and there you can find `MSSOAP30.DLL` which works in 64-bit Excel. In VBA editor select `Tools > References` and click on `Browse...` and browse to that location in shared files and add `MSSOAP30.DLL` manually. This dll is ready for 64-bit architecture.

Answer (score 1):

The SOAP Toolkits have been migrated to Web Services, as per this migration article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973876.aspx. There is a walkthrough tutorial for using the basics of the new .NET SOAP framework. Browsing around, there does appear to be a clear alternative to the new Web Services framework, so I would advise familiarizing yourself with it as much as possible.

Many of the declarations and syntax look to remain relatively the same, e.g. `Set sc = New SoapClient`. I would suggest starting with the walkthrough and then advancing through the reference tools to get your bearings.